# Using _cursor in the _tabOut method

Tags: sas

I'm developing in SAS 9.3 using AF/Frame. I'm using the _tabOut event to verify data in a textbox. If the verification fails I want to display a message and position the cursor in the same textbox. The _cursor method seems to cause the _tabOut event to fire twice thus displaying the message box a second time. The following is a simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
tabOut: method;

DCL LIST InvDNAConc = {"DNA Concentration is invalid."};

SELECT(_self_.name);
  WHEN('txtDNAConc')
    IF TRIM(_self_.TEXT) = '' OR TRIM(_self_.TEXT) = '.' THEN DO;
      reply=MESSAGEBOX(InvDNAConc,'!','O','NOTE');
      reply=reply;
      _self_._cursor();
    END;
  OTHERWISE;
END;

endmethod;
```

There are other objects included in the select statement. I've just stripped it down for simplicity.

If I remove the _cursor method, the message box is displayed only once.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.